# Adding a panel dynamically below tree panel in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am having a tree in a West region of a viewport. On a particular action, dynamically created panels are added in the west region below the existing tree.

After adding the panels, the height of the does not get adjusted and the other panel just overlaps it at the bottom, hiding the tree content beneath them.

Expected Solution :: The tree's height should get automatically adjusted when a new panel is added and the scroll bar should appear in the tree panel if the content of the tree is more than the available height.

Comment: Would you add a snippet ?

Comment: It would be nice if you could create fiddle.sencha.com or at least provide the code.

Comment: @EsNoguera sorry .. you can take a look thorugh fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/pc9692/ebjuuhrh/

Comment: @the script doesn't runs, you can use https://fiddle.sencha.com/ too.